# Error: Body of dispform.aspx of Sharepoint foundation 2013 is disappear

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 foundation, then create an announcement, after that i create [new announcement] then save.

The content of the body field is disappear in dispform.aspx but appear on NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx

I don't know why.

[Click to view error page](https://plus.google.com/photos/109292008911071425273/albums/5910009317935221457?authkey=CMC4tv3fscDHdA)

Please help

Comment: Nobody see this before?

Comment: I'm seeing something similar on my production SharePoint 2013 farm. The test farm is unaffected. Contribute users can see the Body text on all Announcements, except the last 2 that were added. They can see the Body text in the list view and when editing the item, just not when using the default display form to view the item. Site Collection Admins are not affected - they see the Body content even in the default display form.